# How to relocate Linq rows with logic

Tags: .net, linq

I have a LINQ from SQL query that returns sorted rows.
For instance, it will return: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
I am looking for a way to tell the LINQ to cut & paste all the 1's and place it after the 3's, so it will look 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 .

What is the most efficient way to relocate its pointers? (without selecting & deleting & copying)

thanks

Comment: You have to phrase your question less specifically (i.e., state generally what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: I want to take certain rows (that answers a specific query) and relocate them in the dataset

Comment: What identifies the rows you want to move? How do you specify where you want to relocate them?

Comment: doesnt matter, any LABMDA i will put will determin which will move, and I will specify after which number to move

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
query.OrderBy(x => x == 1 : 3.5 ? (float)x);
```

Comment: a value that is between 3 and 4, thus, the 1's get stuck between 3 and 4

Comment: @Himberjack just to tweak the order weightage for value `1`; you can pick anything that's greater than 3 but something less than 4 so it doesn't affect the overall order otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var list = <YourLinqQuery>.ToList();
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(a=> (a==1)? 3.5:a);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the Linq to SQL query like so:

```
var query = from x in context.Table
            let Order = x.RowNum == 1 ? 3.5 : x.RowNum
            orderby Order
            select x;
```

Comment: @Himberjack - The 3.5 is used for sorting, you want the 1 records to appear after 3, but before 4. You can use any number between 3-4, I chose 3.5